# How can I use trace reader object in a clustered sql server environment?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

*I can get trace events in a non clustered sql environment using below code.*

```
TraceServer reader = new TraceServer();

    ConnectionInfoBase ci = new SqlConnectionInfo("localhost");
    ((SqlConnectionInfo)ci).UseIntegratedSecurity = true;

    reader.InitializeAsReader(ci, @"Standard.tdf");

    int eventNumber = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.Write( "{0}\n", reader.GetValue(0).ToString() );
        eventNumber ++;
        if (eventNumber == 10) break;
    }
    reader.Close();
```

How do I refine the code to get the trace events from a clustered environment. Aprreciate any ideas.